# How to calculate t-value for testing whether there is differences between two coefficients

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

I have been given the coefficient values for beta_1Vienna = -0.31 with a standard error of 0.038 and beta_2Amsterdam = -0.27 with a standard error of 0.040. To calculate it I used the formula in the picture, which gave me a t-value of 20, but this would mean I should reject the null, while my professor says to accept it. Can anyone help me with it?

**Calculation for t-statistic**

[image] = 20

**Hypothesis**

[image]

Comment: Questions on homework/school work need to be tagged `self-study` so that you get the benefit of thinking deeply on the problem.

Comment: For the t value I obtain $(-0.31 - (-0.27)) / \sqrt{0.038^2 + (-0.040)^2} = -0.72.$  Where does  "20" come from??

Comment: @whuber as noted in my answer, the OP calculated SE(B1) - SE(B2) rather than SE(B1 - B2). So you have 0.04 / (0.002) = 20

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, @Adam.  I was trying to lead the OP to recognize what the source of their difficulty is.  After all, most people upon reflecting on the meaning of the difference of SEs, and seeing an example where that is negative, will realize that subtracting one SE from another is inherently problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's funny, borderline downright evil, to include $SE(\hat{\beta}_1 - \hat{\beta}_2)$ without any further detail in an elementary class. The truth is that with these details *only* you actually don't have enough information. Cross reference the Welch's T-test for the most commonly accepted solution with non-equal variances. Perhaps you were told that the variances were equal? Or a similar sample size was drawn between either city? Or can we assume the samples are independent?

As for your solution, you probably calculated $SE(\hat{\beta}_1) - SE(\hat{\beta}_2)$. Variance (and SE) is not like multiplication, you can't just "pass it through" the parentheses. Your intuition also should tell you that's wrong. For instance, if the second SE is greater than the first, you would reject the one-sided hypothesis in the wrong direction if significant!

Visualize the normal curves parametrized by their variances and effects when working these kind of problems, update with details, and memorize the Welch's T-test formulation, and apply it here for reference.

Comment: Thanks but what if I had the sample size for each city? e.g., if Vienna n = 207, and Amsterdam n = 195. Would I then be able to "just" use Welch's T-test to calculate whether there is a significant difference between my coefficient?

And also does it matter whether my coefficients are logged or not?

Comment: @RasmusM the $N$ matters because the T-test has an even more complicated formula for the degrees of freedom due to Satterthwaite. Of course, with $N$ so large, you can just use the $Z$ test, so no the $N$ isn't needed in my mind with this large sample. Regarding whether the beta-s are logged, that's a completely different question

Comment: The standard errors are specified and are relatively close, indicating considerations of Welch *etc.* are at best tangential to the question.  Moreover, as it turns out, the DF in this question is immaterial.